# How do I insert into a set?

Tags: c++, insert, set

I know the obvious way is to use the insert function. What I am trying to do is place the phone number given into the Phones map and into the phone_numbers set. It can place it into the map, but when it gets to the phone_numbers set it seg faults. The Add_Phone function and the Phone map are inside a class called Code_Processor

```
class User {
  public:
   string username;
   string realname;
   int points;
   set <string> phone_numbers;
};

map <string, User *> Phones;

int Code_Processor::Add_Phone(string username, string phone) {
    //register the given phone # with given user
    //put the phone on both Phones map and phone_numbers set
    //use .insert()
    User *nUser = new User;
    map <string, User *>::iterator nit;
    nit = Phones.find(username);

    Phones.insert(make_pair(username, nUser));  //put into Phones map
    nit->second->phone_numbers.insert(phone);    //this is where is seg faults!! 


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You search for `username` before you insert into the map, and if the user doesn't exist then `nit` will be the `end` iterator which should not be dereferenced. If you dereference it (like you do) then you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead, to solve your problem, rely on the fact that the [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) functions returns the iterator to the inserted element.

Then you can do something like

```
auto inserted_pair = Phones.insert(make_pair(username, nUser));
if (inserted_pair.first != Phones.end())
{
    inserted_pair.first->phone_numbers.insert(phone);
}
```